# Why can't I copy data in a struct to an openCL cl_mem buffer correctly?

Tags: c, opencl

OK, so I have isolated this down to a very specific problem.

I was under the impression you could pass OpenCL any type of data in an array buffer; ints, chars, your own custom structs, as long as it was all just data and didn't contain pointers to heap objects that the GPU won't be able to retrieve.

Now, I've tried this and I think that it works for a big array of ints, but fails for my array of structs. specifically,

```
cl_mem log_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 
  num_elements * sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);

int* error_codes_in = (int*)malloc(num_elements * sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
  error_codes_in[i] = i;
}

error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, log_buffer, CL_TRUE,
  0, num_elements * sizeof(int), error_codes_in, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

this works fine, and I get an array of numbers on the GPU and can manipulate them successfully, in parallel.

However, when I am using my own custom struct:

```
typedef struct {
  float position[2];
  float velocity[2];
  float radius;
  float resultant_force[2];
} ocl_element_2d_t;
```

(also defined in the kernel, as)

```
const char* kernel_string = 
  "typedef struct { float position[2]; float velocity[2]; float radius; float resultant_force[2]; } ocl_element_2d_t;"...
```

and I use the same/very similar code to write to the GPU version of my struct array:

```
cl_mem gpu_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
  num_elements * sizeof(ocl_element_2d_t), NULL, NULL);

error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, (cl_mem)gpu_buffer, CL_TRUE,
  0, num_elements * sizeof(ocl_element_2d_t), host_buffer, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I get blank values in the GPU, and occasionally garbage (three or four values in 350,) for all of the float values inside the struct. Both return values are `CL_SUCCESS`.

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong? My only thought is that the GPU compiler produces a struct in memory with different gaps, and since the copy method ignores the internal structure of the items and just copies a continguous block of RAM, you end up with mismatches and possible out of phase items. Is it possible that my OS is 64-bit (OS X Lion) on an i7 (quad core), and my GPU is running 32-bit, and this is the problem? It's an ATI Radeon HD 5750, which has no double precision support, and claims to have a 128-bit bus (which may or may not be relevant, I don't know precisely what this stuff means.)

Is there a correct way to do this? Am I going to have to go all FORTRAN and have 7 different arrays, each with their own kernel argument, for the different properties in the struct?

Comment: I don't see where you are actually passing your struct.  You pass in the size, but otherwise it isn't used.

Comment: @0A0D sorry, these are just snippets. I add the buffers as Kernel arguments and successfully execute the Kernel; and I know that part is working because I can get at the integers. I can post more code, if you like, but the post was already getting pretty long... EDIT: Oh, you mean the host data don't you? that is the `host_buffer` argument to `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` in the last snippet.

Comment: You should post the pertinent code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: the operation that is failing is the code that copies the struct array to the GPU memory space - all the set up for that, and the library call itself, have been provided. I don't believe any other code is pertinent.

Comment: That's what I don't understand... where does it copy the struct to the host buffer?

Comment: sorry, mincing my OpenCL jargon perhaps. the 'host' is the CPU and normal RAM. the 'device' is the graphics card. I copy stuff _back_ to the host at the end of the process, but I know for sure that the data doesn't get _to_ the device in the first place (I used the int array, in fact, to test this.) So, nowhere in this code do I 'copy the struct to the host buffer' - I'm copying it from the host to the device and I do it in the second line of the last snippet.

Comment: Right, but where does it send any data of or from the struct to the GPU? You are using the sizeof the struct but nothing from the struct that I can tell.. so that's where I am confused.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4071/discussion-between-tehwalrus-and-0a0d)

Comment: Have you compared the value of sizeof(ocl_element_2d_t) on the host with the target? If they are not identical, perhaps that is a problem.

Comment: @vocaro Thanks, good suggestion. they both come out to 28 when you cast the size_t to an int.

Comment: You should include your Edit as part of your answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credit to [@0A0D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195488/0a0d) for being suspicious of my selective code samples. The problem was indeed in **my failure to initialise the structs correctly**.

My excuse is simply that I'm used to working with struct pointers, not structs, and so writing

```
ocl_element_2d_t element = host_buffer[i];
element.position[0] = 1.2;
element.position[1] = 5.7;
```

was the standard way to add properties to an object. Having had a quick google of structs, I came across a very very basic C tutorial, http://www.asic-world.com/scripting/structs_c.html which pointed out that

```
struct_instance = other_struct_instance;
```

performs a **deep copy**, not a reference copy.

Thus, when I tested the output from the *local* struct variable, the value I was expecting was there, and yet still nowhere near the array in `host_buffer`.

There are probably two lessons here:

1. Make sure you post all the relevant code when asking a StackOverflow question - including all initialisation - so that all possible problems can be considered.
2. When using a library, especially one as complicated as OpenCL, don't assume its developers will have made silly mistakes - they are almost certainly your own!

Comment: I am also getting a very strange problem when passing structs to my kernel.  Up to this point I have no trouble.  Now I am getting strange values in the return host array.  To test, I am literally just using a test kernel that accepts the structs and writes a certain value in the struct to the return buffer.  It is not what was passed in.  I have checked the host side code to ensure that the struct is instantiated properly.  I am completely at a loss.

Comment: my error here was a basic bit of C initialisation - openCL was working fine! I can only suggest that you do a little more [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and if that fails start a new question posting exactly how you initialise the structs, call the OpenCL library, the content of the test kernel, and so on. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your compilers aligns your 'float' structure, but using gcc you you can try:

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

to have it aligned without gaps.

To undo this packing use:

```
#pragma pack()
```

Also you might try to just rearrange the members, like this:

```
typedef struct {
  float position[2];
  float velocity[2];
  float resultant_force[2];
  float radius;
} ocl_element_2d_t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately neither of these techniques makes a difference; separately or together.